# Static page blogger template

Tags: templates, blogger, static-pages

I am trying to create an issue blogger and have problems printing the contents of a static page. I want to show the contents inside a div if a page of static type, I tried the way

```
<b: if cond = 'data: blog.pageType == & quot; static_page & quot;'>
           <div class = 'row page' itemscope = 'itemscope'>

             <! - Blog Post Content Column ->
             <div class = 'col-LG-8 col-lg-offset-2'>

                 <! - Title ->
                 <h1> <data: blog.pageName /> </ h1>

                 <! - Preview Image ->
               <img alt = '' class = 'img-responsive' src = 'http: //placehold.it/900x300'/>

               <hr />

                 <! - Post Content ->
                 <p class = 'lead'> <data: blog.body /> </ p>
```

but the post content does not print and gives me an error dictionary. How I can show this content?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `blog.body` try this:

```
<! - Post Content ->
<p class = 'lead'>
<data: post.body />
</p>
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this, but the page does not show the content, `<p class = 'lead'></p>` appears empty. It is neede any thing else before to access this data?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="staticpage-content">
                  <b:section id="staticPage" showaddelement='no'>
                    <b:widget id='Blog2' locked='true' title='Postagens no blog' type='Blog'>
                        <b:includable id='post' var='post'>
                          <h1><data:post.title/></h1>
                          <data:post.body />
                        </b:includable>
                    </b:widget>
                  </b:section>
```